# Twilio Function help (Build a community SMS group chat with Twilio Functions and Google Sheets)

Tags: twilio

I followed [this](https://www.twilio.com/blog/community-sms-group-chat-twilio-functions-google-sheets) guide to setup this service:

I have this all set up and working but what confused me is, when someone sends a message to the Twilio number. It will send the message to all the users in the google sheets but when the users receive the messages, it doesn't show who sent the message. It says From: (The persons name who the message was sent to rather than where it was sent from.

For example:
Person A send a message to Twilio Number

Person B receives the message as follows:
`From: Person B` (should have person A's info there)

Any help from the developer of this would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not the developer but in the `handler` where you call `twiml.message` change:

```
twiml.message(
  `From: ${row.Name} (${row.House}).\nBody: ${event.Body}`,
  {
    to: row.Number,
  }
);
```

to read:

```
twiml.message(
  `From: ${from.Name}.\nBody: ${event.Body}`,
  {
    to: row.Number,
  }
);
```

And you should be set. The `From` controls what's displayed.

Comment: Thanks! This worked. Now when the message is received by everyone eles, it shows FROM:(sender phone number). I would prefer to have it show their name and not the phone number.

Comment: Do you think it is at all possible to have this work with two google sheets with each sheet having unique phone numbers on them? I could then have two groups using the same Twilio number.